# java.net HttpURLConnection Content-Type mismatch

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection, mime-types, content-type

I would like to develop a [telegram bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots) that searches relevant images in the [iqdb.org](http://www.iqdb.org/) database. I have successfully captured the user's image and turned it into a link. However, the iqdb side always tells me that my MIME is `application/octet-stream` instead of `image/jpeg` even though I already made the connection `con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");`

I have tried to access link of the file in my browser, it worked as intended - my browser downloaded a jpeg file automatically.

Code:

```
//define the target url.
URL target = new URL("https://iqdb.org/index.xml?url=https://api.telegram.org/file/botAPITokenHidden/photos/file_1.jpg);

//establish GET connection.
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) target.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
```

Response from iqdb:

```
<error message="file_1.jpg: Not an image or image format not supported (server says it is application/octet-stream )." info="<br>Make sure the source URL points directly to the image, not to the page containing the image, and that the server does not block hotlinking."/>
```

Does this mean that telegram blocked hotlinking or I didn't set up the Content-Type of the connection correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `url` in your query param seems to be invalid. Try to fetch the image by your browser through `https://api.telegram.org/file/botAPITokenHidden/photos/file_1.jpg` and you'll get a `404` status code. You have to make sure the image is really saved on telegram.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. The ```botAPITokenHidden``` part was actually my bot API token, so I hid that.